# What do the icons in Eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse, icons

- What do the icons in the Eclipse debugger mean?
- What do the icon decorators in Eclipse mean?
- What do the icons in Eclipse's Package Explorer mean?
- What do the little letters on top of Eclipse icons mean?
- What's the difference between the two error icons in Eclipse (the x in the red circle and the one with the light bulb)?

I just came to SO looking for this, didn't find it, and found it on my own elsewhere. But I thought it would be good for SO to have the answer for future reference; I wondered about them all the time when I was new to Eclipse (this was before I discovered SO).

Comment: Some of the icons are very intuitive, like the one for annotations. But others, I have no idea whatsoever.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

This is a fairly comprehensive list from the Eclipse documentation.  If anyone knows of another list — maybe with more details, or just the most common icons — feel free to add it.

Latest: [JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

2019-06: [JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

2019-03: [JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

2018-12: [JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

2018-09: [JDT Icons](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-icons.htm)

Photon: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Oxygen: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Neon: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Mars: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Luna: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Kepler: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Juno: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

Indigo: <strike>[JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)</strike>

Helios: [JDT Icons](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

There are also some CDT icons at the bottom of this [help page](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_cproj_view.htm).

If you're a Subversion user, the icons you're looking for may actually belong to Subclipse; see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean/3920248#3920248) for more on those.

Comment: @ Mario Marinato -br- Me too! Apparently Google doesn't good enough of a job for this one because all I could find for the Outline View was [this](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_outline_view.htm) which doesn't really cover all icon combinations such as the green dot with the tiny arrow.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a crazy idea to have a text rollover or some clickable thing come up with a human readable version of the meaning. There's cases where icons are nearly useless, and then there's eclipse icons.

Comment: That's amazing. They have a web page with all of the text you'd need to display, but they don't do it in the application. Considering you can refactor whole projects that does tons of complex code changing, it's amazing they don't have the icon's meaning inline somewhere.

Comment: I asked for exactly this (hovers inside Eclipse) a long while back and it was declined.  Sigh.

Comment: In Eclipse Luna, I am also seeing an undocumented brown 'D' adornment for "default methods". https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405704

Comment: I was looking for versioning icons too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978553/what-does-the-brown-asterisk-icon-on-a-file-mean-in-eclipse

Comment: More versioning-related Icons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3920248/8067821

Comment: This  list is not comprehensive.  Content assist icons are all missing from this list.

Comment: Where can we get licensing information of all these icons? Can we simply modify them and use them under EPL?

Comment: Extra credit if you memorize them all.

Answer (score 17):

I can't find a way to create a table with icons in SO, so I am uploading 2 images.
[image: Objects Icons]

[image: Decorator icons]

Answer (score 8):

In eclipse help documentation, we can all icons information as follows. Common path for all eclipse versions except eclipse version:

[image]

https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?nav=%2F1