# What do the icons for methods in Eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse, icons, package-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean)

In the "Package Explorer" in the Eclipse IDE, I can click on a Java class and list all its methods. The methods are displayed with a few different icons before the name, including a green circle or a red square.

What do these icons mean? Is there a webpage that explains them?

Comment: Subsumed by http://stackoverflow.com/q/1561336/191776

Answer (score 138, accepted):

[image: green circle]Green circle indicates a public method

[image: red square]Red square indicates a private method

[image]Yellow diamond indicates a protected method

[image]Blue triangle indicates default (package visible) method

[This page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) gives an overview of all the icons used in Eclipse JDT. [This page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) explains what the different access levels mean in Java terms, in case you aren't familiar with that.

Comment: +1 for the embedded icons :-)

Comment: How does Eclipse label those classes that have a `main` method?

Comment: @KareemJeiroudi these are labelled with a small green "run" arrow overlaid on the class's icon. In the [icon reference linked above](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) you can see what this looks like under *type with public static void main(String[] args)*

Answer (score 1):

Methods with the red square are private and the ones with the green circle are public.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

green circle - Usually a public method.
red square - private method.
yellow - protected