# What is the meaning of blue triangle icon in Eclipse Package Explorer view?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, icons

Can someone please point me to where one can get more understanding on the meaning of the blue triangle icons in Eclipse and its derivatives (STS, etc.) and possibly modifying them:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: here is a reference to some of the icons in eclipse. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957321/what-do-the-icons-for-methods-in-eclipse-mean

Comment: Blue Triangle is usually the "default method" icon, but that wouldn't be shown on a file. Not sure what else it might be. Any plug-in you have installed can contribute icons to the view. Generally icons are built-in to the plug-in and are not easily changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it means a default/package-protected *class*, much like how @greg-449 recognized its use with default/package-protected members.