# How to check the icon meaning in the eclipse (project explorer)?

Tags: eclipse

In the eclipse, there are different icons before files and projects. I am asking if there is an explanation for those icons.

Comment: @Harry:  Does that work?  It doesn't for me with the decorations I tried.

Comment: @Mark Peters it does work for me. At least, in Eclipse Windows version.

Comment: @Mark: if OP wants details for the icon on tool bar then hovering works and if OP is asking about any thing else then I may be mistaken him.

Comment: Sorry, modify the question. I want to know the icons in the project explorer

Comment: @user496949: When you press `Ctrl+N` a wizard will open and you can see a list with icons and it's short name and as per I think it is sufficient to understand.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

Comment: The link from user908170 unfortunately no longer points to anything relevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see a list of label decorations enabled in Eclipse by going to `Window->Preferences` and then `General->Appearance->Label Decorations`.  This describes the set of decorations, but unfortunately not a picture of what the icon looks like (silly oversight IMO).  Still, you might find it useful for seeing what the possibilities are.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Indeed this is useful. Though the preferences dialog does not display the icons, you can check/uncheck various providers and see the effect. So you can guess (yep) based on the provider, what the overlays mean. On the same occasion, disable unneeded providers to hide confusing icons. For example, disable git or svn status if you use external software for version control.

Answer (score 29):

Considering the meaning of "[Label decoration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_label_decorator%3F)", you won't ever have a formal description of *all* the icons in a project Explorer: it depends on the plugins you have installed.

[image]

A plugin like EGit for instance will modify those icons with its own [list of decorators](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State#Label_Decorations):

[image]

As [Harry Joy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559070/harry-joy), mentions in the comments, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> "new project" dialog is the closest way to list all of those icons.

[image]

It can be helpful though to know about the "[User Interface Guidelines](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines)" for Eclipse to grasp their more general meaning:

For example, in the [style section](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines#Style_.26_Design):

[image]

> The two dominant colors, ***blue*** and ***yellow***, bring harmony to the overall presentation of the user interface.
>   Themselves complementary, blue and yellow form a base on which to apply accent colors

[image]

> ***Brown*** is used less than the other colors mentioned, but it is generally associated with specific types of objects: the Java "package", "bundle", and the "Enterprise Java Bean (EJB)".

Comment: I see what you mean about plugins using additional decorators. But it seems like they should have a list of the built-in ones for Java, etc. I couldn't find this by doing search in eclipse help. The help pages on Label decorations just give general info and link to the Preferences page for enabling/disabling specific ones, without showing what they look like visually.

Ah, I just found JDT icon decorators linked in answer to another question:
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

Answer (score 20):

This page contains meaning of all eclipse icons: 
http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

**UPDATE:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1561346/1587910) contains icon meanings per Eclipse version.

Comment: Helpful link, but to be picky: those are the Eclipse Java Development Tools icons, not all Eclipse icons.  Anyhow, updated link for Luna:  http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

Answer (score 1):

For the subversive plugin for Eclipse Neon navigate to Window:Preferences:Team:SVN:Label Decorations, which will show you options and a preview like this:
[Label Decorations Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy7Go.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDT, **[this](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_project_explorer_view.htm)** help page may help. Unfortunately, it does not display the icon decorations.