# Eclipse subversion exclamation marks

Tags: eclipse, svn, ide

I'm seeing some strange behaviour with Subversion in Eclipse IDE.

I'm using the subversion plugin from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/

I've screen captured the problem below with exclamation marks next to the views package and contents...

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/29dhaqf/7]

Team > Commit seems to have no effect, although no errors are reported. After commit files are still marked as changed (with the ">" symbol next to them)

The code executes fine and there are no errors or warnings in the marked files.

It's hard to see how there can be conflicts given that I'm the only one using this repository, with only one computer. And I don't use any other editor or commit mechanism.

I'm not too sure what's going on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to rename the source folder, remove all .svn folders and files, remove all .project files. Then create the project afresh, download the source from the repositiory and then copy the local changes back into the folder.

Not sure what was going on here but it's fixed for now.

Answer (score 0):

Its to signify build path errors, in the case of subclipse, its a way of saying when run on the server the path may not be available.

This has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640823/what-does-the-red-exclamation-point-icon-in-eclipse-mean)

Comment: I'd read that page. But this isn't a java project, the code works fine when run on the server (localhost) and there are no problems reported in the problems view with the decorated files. And commits are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exact problem a bit more easily by just deleting the .svn folders in the bugged folders, then refreshing the workspace view in Eclipse (at which point the "!" changes to a "?"), updating via the Team context menu, then committing via the Team context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar problem – One day some of my source code files were marked with red exclamation points and the SVN status became OBSTRUCTED.  I look up this condition and found some suggestions that the .svn folder may be corrupted.  After checking that folder and found it to be fine, I finally spotted a difference of version number at the project level.  Someone had committed to the project and now the repository has a newer version number, although the files that I was working with remained unchanged.

So I did Team|Update and brought the project version in sync with the repository and the red exclamation points disappeared.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case those were files that were deleted externally and not by subversion. I just did an svn delete on the files and that worked for me. A lot easier then deleting the project and recreating it or deleting .svn directories.

svn 1.8 -> http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html