# ClassNotFoundException when trying to run a previously correctly running application

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project 'eartquake' in Eclipse containing several packages. The project icon  contains a red exclamation mark. I cannot find out what it means. When trying to run any package of this project I get the ClassNotFoundException error. When I run for example the AppQuake applet from package earthquake I get the error shown below. The .class file is in the `build` directory of the package. It has run before. Other applets from other projects still do run. What am I doing wrong?

```
load: class earthquake.AppQuake.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: earthquake.AppQuake.class
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: so when the project used to compile: what did you change?

Comment: Can you describe the project file structure and the App.Quake package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red exclamation mark means that the IDE is notifying that there are build errors in your project: [see documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm)

On Stackoverflow you can find someone who had the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640823/what-does-the-red-exclamation-point-icon-in-eclipse-mean) and a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585312/2728768) in case you changed the project structure and left some dead dependencies.

Your project is probably misconfigured, or missing some dependencies in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks, I had focused too much on the ClassNotFound. It appeared to be a build error indeed. I found out that the `.classpath` was corrupted, but that took some time to find out. +1 for the links that ultimately helped me.