# What do the PDE icons in Eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-pde

Following the question ["What do the icons in Eclipse mean?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean) that has an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1561346/60114)

I hope to find what all the icons and icon decorations of the ["Plug-ins"](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/views/plugins.htm&cp=4_3_8_1) and ["Plug-ins Dependencies"](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/views/plugins.htm&cp=4_3_8_1) views of the PDE

[image: Like those but not limited to those]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can fill in most of those:

**Main Icons**

[image: Plugin] : Plugin

[image: Fragment] : Fragment

**Overlays**

[image: Exported] : Re-exported by parent plugin

[image: Optional] : Optional import

[image: External] : Exists in the target platform (not the workspace)