# Eclipse PDE: Cannot use slf4j.simple plugins from current target platform as plugin dependency (purple icon)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde, manifest.mf, target-platform, update-site

**Summary of Problem:**

I cannot use all of the plugins from a p2 Software Site ( = Updatesite ) as dependencies. They are listed in the target platform with a purple icon and  they do not appear in the plug-in selection list when trying to add as dependencies to a MANIFEST.MF file.

What's the reason and what can I do to use the plug-ins as dependencies?

**Details:**

I am having an Eclipse Plugin project which uses a target platform defined by a target definition file:

- With the target definition editor file I have added a "Software Site" hosted on a corporate nexus:
- In the 'Add Software Site' UI I selected all the available bundles. ( The Software Site consists of a p2 repository which I have created myself via p2-maven-plugin). Among others the Software site contains the plug- ins slf4j.api slf4j.simple.
- I checked the availability of the plug-ins by opening the target definition file in the corresponding eclipse editor and klick on "Show location content". The plug ins mentioned abover are listed:

  - slf4j.api has a **blue** plug-in icon to the left
  - slf4j.simple has a **purple** plug-in icon ( The  icon is horizontally cut and only shows the lower half of the plug)

Now I want to use the plugins as dependencies in a PDE plug-in Project.
- In the Manifest editor I go to 'dependencies' tab, klick 'Add' and search for slf4j.

**Problem:** In the 'Matching' items list , only slf4j.api does appear. slf4j.simple does not appear.

What do I need to do to use slf4j.simple as a dependency?

( According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277288/what-do-the-pde-icons-in-eclipse-mean) stackoverflow answer. The purple icons are Fragments - not sure what that means )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add fragments as dependencies. A fragment is just an extra piece of code for the fragment's 'host' plugin. They often include code which is only required for a particular platform. Fragments don't provide any additional APIs.

You just specify the host plugin as the dependency and the fragments will be included.