# how to hide yellow cylinder decorations on the right bottom corner of icons in project explore view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

i created a C++ project called us_txn_svc in eclipse kepler.
The workspace location is in /data/work/usfsi/, the project location in /data/work/usfsi/fsi_svc_us/us_txn_svc.
In project explore view, the proejct us_txn_svc is shown with a "remote" decoration on the icon and a suffix like " [fsi_svc_us echo]", echo is my user name on this computer. all files under this project are also shown with a "remote" decoration.

how to configurate my workspace to hide these useless infomation?

a snapshot:
[image: you can see that some icons with a yellow cylinder at the right-bottom corner]

Answer (score 14):

The icon overlay decoration tells you the file is under version control, the information in [] gives you more version control information such as the repository.

You can usually turn all the decorations off by going to `Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations` and unselecting your version control system (Git, SVN, CVS etc.)

You can fine tune the information shown for by version control in "Preferences > Team" ("Preferences > Version Control (Team)" in newer versions of Eclipse), select your version control system and look for `Label Decorations`.

Comment: Thank you. I just wasn't finding this one in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean

Answer (score 2):

Hey this should give you a good idea of this and more Eclipse Egit icons:

[image: image describing Eclipse icons for Egit]

- **dirty** (folder) - At least one file below the folder is dirty; that
  means that it has changes in the working tree that are neither in the
  index nor in the repository. tracked - The resource is known to the
  Git repository. untracked - The resource is not known to the Git
  repository.
- **ignored** - The resource is ignored by the Git team
  provider. Here only the preference settings under Team -> Ignored
  Resources and the "derived" flag are relevant. The .gitignore file is
  not taken into account.
- **dirty** - The resource has changes in the
  working tree that are neither in the index nor in the repository.
- **staged** - The resource has changes which are added to the index. Not
  that adding to the index is possible at the moment only on the commit
  dialog on the context menu of a resource.
- **partially-staged** - The resource has changes which are added to the index and additionally
  changes in the working tree that are neither in the index nor in the
  repository.
- **added** - The resource is not yet tracked by but added to
  the Git repository.
- **removed** - The resource is staged for removal from
  the Git repository.
- **conflict** - A merge conflict exists for the file.
- **assume-valid** - The resource has the "assume unchanged" flag. This
  means that Git stops checking the working tree files for possible
  modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell Git when
  you change the working tree file. This setting can be switched on
  with the menu action Team->Assume unchanged (or on the command line
  with git update-index--assume-unchanged).