# What means an '!' at eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm programming in Java with Eclipse, and after a time appears a

> '!'

in some class. What's that means?

Comment: Where does this appear?

Comment: A little more context, please? Where does this appear? Can you click on it?

Comment: '!' means a `not`, if ur talking about booleans. _This is not a good question_ could be stated as `!good_Question`.

Comment: Is this in the code? Or a marker? Or in the package explorer?

Comment: Put your mouse pointer over it and wait a bit (don't click).  An explanatory balloon will show.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is...

- a warning icon [image]. then your code requires requires review.
- build path error icon [image] - check your build dependencies

Reference: [What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean)

Comment: Yes, somethig like the warning icon, but a ! icon

Comment: no idea what you're describing there, post a link to an image and I'll add it to the question...:)

Answer (score 0):

Exclamation mark in Eclipse means that Eclipse has detected some fault in your code but it has not been deemed critical enough to be marked as an error (Red color X marker) so it displays it instead as a yellow exclamation mark Signifying it as a warning not an error.

Answer (score 0):

It means that line was never used in the code like any import or variables.