# What does this icon in Eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse

I am referring specifically to the green plus sign in the screenshot below.

[edit] This is taken from "Outline" view, and I am coding in Java.

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse icon, green plus sign]

Comment: where it is in which view?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK it is in the Outline view, where the class/fields/methods are listed.

Comment: are you using PyDev,or CDT or JDT. Mean to say which file you are viewing is it Python file(.py), C/C++ file(.c,.cpp) or java(.java) file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:
[What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean)

From the icon index, the plus means add, the C means public class, and the warning means that there is a java element warning.

So from what I can assume, it means you can add a new public class, but is warning you of possible problems with your current project.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The "add a new public class" doesn't make sense because this screenshot was from Outline view, where Eclipse shows the class/fields/methods.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Also, do you happen to have any extensions or packages that are not vanilla?

Comment: The screenshot of the icon is above. I would show the context, but I deleted that file and can't find the icon again. I do have another extension, maybe that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The green + sign is an overlay that shows that the visibility of the class is set to public. The orange is a warning that there could be a potential issue in that class. This might not necessarily stop your class from running or performing well. It is just telling you to be aware of something that may or may not be harmful.