# Where are these Eclipses PyDev icons defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Eclipse + PyDev. Where can I find the definition of the following icons?
I searched a bit but no results.

I guess the C means class and M means Method. But what do the other slightly different ones mean?

As I checked, the `tuple` and `str` are both classes within the `__builtins__` module, why their icons are different?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think PyDev icons are documented anywhere. If you are really curious about when exactly they are used - you can dig into the PyDev source code (it is on [GitHub](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev)). All icons are deinfed in [plugins/org.python.pydev/icons/](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/tree/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/icons), and file names are very meaningful. You could also find the list of all icons in [plugins/org.python.pydev.shared_ui/src/org/python/pydev/shared_ui/UIConstants.java](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev.shared_ui/src/org/python/pydev/shared_ui/UIConstants.java) from where you could also navigate to a particular icon usages.

For example, among icons you've listed:

- [C](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/icons/new/class_obj.gif) stands for a class
- [M](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/icons/new/method_obj.gif) stands for a method
- [small red and yellow squares](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/icons/field_private_obj.gif) strand for private and protected fields respectively
- [blue circle](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/icons/new/attrpub_obj.gif) - for a public attribute
- all [builtins have a dedicated icon](https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/development/plugins/org.python.pydev/icons/builtin_obj.gif) indeed - visually looking same way as private fields (bummer)

Answer (score 2):

I found this big list:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

The C is for class, the bars mean private. The red square box means private field, apparently. I don't see the circle, though.

I found that link in this question:
[What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean)

Answer (score 0):

This dose not really answer your question specifically, but it sure will solve a lot of your problems. I used to use pyDev plugin, and I liked some parts of it but it wasn't great. I found pyCharm and am a huge advocate, its the best IDE for python out there, totally recommend it man, good luck. The documentation and ease of use is just so much better with pyCharm. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/