# Strange sign in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am doing a Maven project in Eclipse. But in Project explorer there are some strange yellow signs
 [image]

Take a look. What is meaning of the battery size yellow sign? Besides, the red cross sign beside "java resourse", inside the folder no error, so why this red cross?
Edit: I can not find this sign in that sign list that has been given as a ans in that questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean)

Comment: really !! down vote!!!  Before downvoting me please help me to find the meaning of sign in that answer..i search through the link that the ans provided and i could not find.....thanks user2953113 for providing a  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery size yellow sign indicates that this project is tracked by a source code repository. If you look at the markers tab (Window > Show View > Markers), you can see the list of errors which is causing the red cross sign to appear.