# Eclipse outline window not showing all members of a class

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is how my eclipse outline window looks like:

[image]

As highlighted with red box, I dont understand why is that `private` is shown like that:

1. It points correctly to my next method which is indeed `private`. But then it shows only `private` not the method `name`
2. The icon prefixed to `private` is something new I find. What is that?
3. There are more methods in my code that follows this particular method. Those methods are not at all listed in the Outline window. Why is that?

Whats wrong is going on with this method which is making Outline window behave in such a way? Is my code culprit?

Comment: parsing error in eclipse maybe how does the code look around that method?

Comment: that new icon you are refeering to is that of default modifier

Comment: @Mahesha999 You can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean#1561346) to find out which icons are used by Eclipse JDT. However, I never seen this icon. The look reminds me AJDT but don't remember such icon.

Comment: @KumarAbhinav I think problem is the arrow ? Not triangle form ?

Comment: Very sorry not to tell at first. I am using Groovy Grails Tools Suite. But its  based on eclipse only.