# eclipse thumbnails, what do the additions mean?

Tags: eclipse

Sorry for my vague question, but I'm missing the words to be more to the point. That's part of my question.

I'm using Eclipse Mars.  Several views display little images next to, e.g., project names.  Furthermore, these images are enriched by additional graphical features, depending on the properties and states of the entities they are attached to.  So,

- How are these images called?
- How are the additions called?
- How do I find out, what a specific addition means?

For example, I have no clue about the meaning of the strange antlers on the bottommost image in the following screen.

[image: screen show of Eclipse Mars, Java projects]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called 'decorations' or 'decorators'. They are added by various plugins to provide additional information about the file / folder / projects. Decorations can also be added to the beginning or end of the label text.

For example the first three projects in your image are Java projects (small J at the top right), they are under source control (bottom right image) and they all have some warnings about problems (warning sign at the bottom left).

You can control the display of many of these images in the Preferences in the 'General > Appearance > Label Decorations' page. Other decorations are controlled in other preference pages specific to the plugin that provides them (for example 'Team > SVN > Label Decorations').

Because they are added by many plugins it is hard to give a list of what they all mean. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1561346/2670892) lists some of them.

Plugins use the `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` to declare decorations.

I'm not sure but my guess is the 'strange antlers' decoration are because you have an ANTLR project.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the official icon reference for the **basic** icons and decorators](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm).

Plugins (including standard plugins) will add additional decorations.  For example, the ones used by Git are listed in `Preferences>Team>Git>Label Decorations`, along with a key.  You can enable/disable plugin-specific decorations in `Preferences>General>Appearance>Label Decorations`.

The antlers in your selected icon are from the [ANTLR plugin](http://antlreclipse.sourceforge.net/).  So that project is an ANTLR project (as well as being a Git-tracked project that causes a warning, per the other icons).

I hope that helps!