# Why does the dirt/garbage icon mean in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I could not find this icon in the eclipse help as suggested here [What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean). I believe the icon comes from a plugin or something like that but really not sure. I don't have any warnings in my workspace or errors, I'm completely stumped as to what it means:
[image]

Comment: Where does it appear? Does it have a tooltip (what does it say)? What does it do if you click on it? What plugins do you have?

Comment: It's a maven project and that is the icon for the project.

Comment: What programming language? You might get an idea from looking at the project natures listed in the `.project` file for the project.

Comment: It's just a Java sub-module project. Nothing special, and has this poo on it lolz

Comment: `I believe the icon comes from a plugin or something` - What plugins do you have installed?