# What is the Icon Decoration Meaning in Eclipse (Neon)

Tags: eclipse

I have this spontaneous change in icon decorations in my java file icons in Eclipse.

[image]

What do these decorations on the icon mean, and is there a legend describing the meanings of all text decorations?

There is a Stack Exchange [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean) about file [icons](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm), which is helpful, but no comprehensive info about icon decorations.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow caution means you have warnings. The red arrow is probably from svn, and means switched.  See [Eclipse SVN Label Decorations](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_label_decors.php) for more on SVN label decorators.  And look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean/1561346#1561346) answer for a list of common JDT decorators.