# What is the reason for grey mark on top of my project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a grey (or brown?) mark on top of my projects here:

[image: Click Here For Image]

Does anyone know what this means and what I should I do about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the icons in Eclipse mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561336/what-do-the-icons-in-eclipse-mean)

Comment: It is not clear which part of the image you are asking about.

Comment: @JoSSte In Eclipse icons that icon is not listed.

Comment: @greg-449 the grey icon next to M.

Comment: It visualizes a project nature that I do not know (maybe Perl or Camel; unfortunately, the Maven-`M` covers a part of the decoration icon). In the _Navigator_ view open the file `.project` and tell us which `<nature>` (beside the Maven nature) there are.

Comment: @howlger these are the natures.
<natures>
  <nature>org.fusesource.ide.project.RiderProjectNature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
  <nature>org.maven.ide.eclipse.maven2Nature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
 </natures>

Answer (score 2):

This icon says it's an **Apache Camel project**.

Obviously, you have [Red Hat Fuse Tooling for Eclipse](https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-fuse) installed, identifiable by the `org.fusesource.ide.project.RiderProjectNature` project nature, which is visualized on project level by the following decoration icon (see [`camel_project_16x16.png` at GitHub](https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-fuse/blob/master/editor/plugins/org.fusesource.ide.project/icons/camel_project_16x16.png)):

[image: camel_project_16x16.png]

Unfortunately, the Maven-`M` covers the camel's head.